# Passing special character as argument

Tags: c, bash

I need to pass a string whose hex is `00 2C 00 21`  to my program as the command line argument which i am unable to do.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

// argv[1] should have the string that the above hex represents 

//... the program will use that string inside the program

//...also please explain what should i do if i (am/am not) allowed to modify the source  

}
```

Since 00 is NULL character i am unable to represent it in command line and pass it to the program. Also i need to pass string composed of various other characters  whose hex values are like  01 or 02 (for eg) which you cannot enter directly from the keyboard and pass as an argument.

**What should i do so that my program receives the string whose hex representation is `00 2C 00 21`**.

```
$./a.out " what should i write here?  "
```

Comment: Is this string supposed to be encoded as UTF-16 or something similar? It's certainly not a C string which is terminated by `\0`. If you are working on Windows the solution for wide char support on the command line is to use `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])`

Comment: Do you need to pass the bytes sequence as parameter, or would it be an option to have the program read it from standard input? In case of the latter you could do `./a.out <<< $'\x00\x2c\x00\x21'` and inside the program just read from `stdin`.

Comment: yes i  need to pass the bytes sequence as parameter.

Comment: This is what things like things like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) are for: encoding arbitrary binary data using a restricted character set.

Comment: even though you can pass almost arbitrary bytes as a string on a bash command line using `$'…'` syntax and smart escaping, this has its limitations. in particular, bash's internal string representation cannot handle zero-bytes (because of bash's C-string zero termination). you can never pass zero-bytes from bash to anywhere, because bash doesn't "allow" zero bytes internally, like many of the command line tools. the best you can do is to use `printf` (and consorts) to generate your zeros and pipe them straight into your program.

Comment: @alk your suggestion won't work, because the zero bytes in the string never make it through the bash-shell... try `hd <<< $'\x00'` to see what I mean. This hexdump from a bash string should print a single `0x0a` for the silent implicit linebreak but it will never print the zero byte.

Answer (score 4):

You should make your program accept a string with escapes in it, and parse them yourself. So it would be invoked like so:

```
$ ./myprogram '\x00\x2c\x00\x21'
```

for instance (the `\x` matches what C itself uses, so can be familiar to users). The single quotes are to protect the backslashes from the shell, not 100% sure and not at a proper prompt right now.

The result won't be a string, since strings in C cannot contain 0-characters.

Here's an example of how this could look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static size_t decode(void *buf, size_t buf_max, const char *s)
{
    unsigned char *put = buf;
    unsigned char * const put_max = put + buf_max;
    while (*s != '\0' && put != put_max)
    {
        if (*s == '\\')
        {
            ++s;
            if (*s == '\\')
                *put++ = *s++;
            else if (*s == 'x')
            {
                ++s;
                char *endp;
                const unsigned long v = strtoul(s, &endp, 16);
                if (endp == s)
                    break;
                *put++ = (unsigned char) v;
                s = endp;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        else
            *put++ = *s++;
    }
    return put - (unsigned char *) buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char buf[32];
    const size_t len = decode(buf, sizeof buf, "\\x0hello\\x1\\xaa\\xfe\\xed");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        printf("%x\n", buf[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the test "driver" in `main()` would be replaced in your case, you want to pass e.g. `argv[1]` to `decode()`. The double backslashes protect against the C compiler, we really want to end up with a string containing backslash escapes.

Comment: For bash it should be `./myprogram $'\x00\x2c\x00\x21'`. No need to parse then.

Comment: @alk Uh, but you really can't have 0-characters in a string, so `argv[1]` would have a really strange value. It's not string data, and must be parsed by the application from the external string representation.

Comment: Just tested this and it turned out I gave bad advice, as when passing `$'\x00\x2c\x00\x21'` everything after the 1st `NUL` does not make it into `argv[1]`. Hu! Did this on Cygwin using GCC 7.4.0.

Comment: @alk what does $ do in `$'\x00\x2c\x00\x21'` i am not so good with bash

Comment: @rimalonfire: bash interprets the following `'\x00\x2c\x00\x21'`  as four byte values which then are passed to the program called. For example do an `echo $'\x41\x42'` and get `AB`.

Comment: @unwind can you please write some code for what you meant

Comment: @rimalonfire Okay. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to pass zero byte to a program argument using bash or any other shell. This is just because it is not possible in the C standard.

C standard says [C11 5.1.2.2.1p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2) (emphasis mine):

> ... the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints:
>   - ...
>   - If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to **strings**, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. ...
>   - ...

A "string" is [C11 7.1.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1) (emphasis mine):

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters **terminated by** and including the **first** null character. ... The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character and the value of a string is the sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.

The "null character" is a `byte with all bits set to 0` [C11 5.2.1p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p2). It is a zero. On the first "null character" the string terminates. If an array of characters has embedded zero bytes in it, it could not be a string (heh, in the exact sense, see [note 78](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note78), a string literal may not be a string, because it can have embedded null characters). You cannot pass multiple `0x00` values embedded in arguments to a C program, as that wouldn't be a "string" that you are passing.

The proper way it to write your own parser around it, that will accept "strings" (ie. `./a.out "00 2C 00 21"`) and convert to zero bytes yourself.

For your use case, if it is simple, I could present a simpler parser then in the other answer. You could ex. pass an argument with all bytes incremented by 1, then decrement by 1 in your program.

Or you could pass special byte value, like ex. `0xff` (if your implementation and operating system and environment supports passing `0xff` bytes) in place of `0x00`, and replace them in your program. This option is presented below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   assert(argc >= 2);
   for (size_t i = 0, max = strlen(argv[1]); i < max; ++i) {
        // replace all 0xff by 0x00
        if ( (0xff & argv[1][i]) == 0xff) {
           argv[1][i] = 0x00;
        }
   }
   // use argv[1]
   for (size_t i = 0, max = 4; i < max; ++i) { 
       printf("argv[1][%d] = 0x%02x\n", i, 0xff & argv[1][i]);
   } 
}
```

and call with:

```
./a.out $'\xff\x2c\xff\x2c'
```

Tested on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NecessaryPaleConfig).

The `$'...'` is interpreted by bash as [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). The `\xff` are interpreted as hex constants, so the first argument will be equal to `(char[]){0xff, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x2c, 0x00}`. After you substitute `0xff` for `0x00`, it will become `(char[]){0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x2c, 0x00}` and you can use the first 4 bytes.

Comment: "*could pass special byte value, like `0xff`*" hm, so a real `0xff` cannot be passed in.

Comment: @alk You just need a more complex encoding scheme. For example, use 0xff as an "escape" byte; two 0xff should be treated as a single null byte, while 0xff followed by, well, anything else really can be treated as a single 0xff.